# I want to have python hold down a key for me

Tags: python, keyboard, pycharm, minecraft, pyautogui

I got my script to work with typing out keys, but for some reason, those keys do not work in Minecraft. Although, typing Minecraft messages in the chat are no problem. I'm trying to get python to move my own character.

In my script, I tried to use pyautogui, the mouse in Minecraft works but not keys such as `w`, `a`, `s`, or `d`. Is there another import or way to hold down a key that actually works in Minecraft?

```
def hold_W (hold_time):
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press('w')
```

Doing this and calling it worked for writing texts, but for some reason does not register in Minecraft? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python" to learn this stuff, the book states that pyautogui cannot be used on video games on Windows. I am not sure how to fix this, but the link to the book is here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter20/
Also, you can go to the documentation of pyautogui here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to see if the games feature has been added. My greatest regrets that I cannot solve this problem for you. If it makes you feel better, pyautogui *does* work on .io games.

Comment: Yes I don't think pyautogui will work for the keyboard but it doesn't have to be that specifically. Anything from python that works will help a lot.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ might work.

Comment: YES! IT WORKS. I used time.sleep() after the press key and then releasing after the wait. For some reason that method doesn't work for everything else but for some reason I tried it on this one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Different video games have different ways of detecting keystrokes, so to find a thing that will work on all video games you might need to get your hands dirty and do some stuff I have no clue how to do.